# How to use multiple isotope filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jquery-isotope

How can I use multiple isotope filters?

my first filter: checkbox is checked=> hide all users with .no-avatar class!

```
            $("#foto_filter").on("change",function(){
                  if($(this).is(":checked")) {

                       $grid.isotope({filter: ['*:not(.no-avatar)' ]});  // zeig alli divs mit Fotis also ohni .no-avatar class
            }else{

                $grid.isotope({filter: '*' })   // show all
            }
        })
```

second filter: uses the jquery slider with 2 handles - show me user with age between x and y

```
            $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 18,
            max: 100,
            values: [ 18, 50 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " Jahre - " + ui.values[ 1 ]+" Jahre" );
                $grid.isotope({
                       filter: function() {
                        // _this_ is the item element. Get text of element's .number
                        var number = $(this).find('.age').text();
                        // return true to show, false to hide
                        return (parseInt( number, 10 ) >= ui.values[ 0 ]) && (parseInt( number, 10 ) <= ui.values[ 1 ]) ;  // here is the filter

                    }
                })

            }
        });
```

Both of the filters work perfectly separatly. It is a XOR, what I want is to combine them! Use AND.  How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share a link to a jsfiddle or codepen so it's easier to work out a solution?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p46nxug9/ In this example the checkbox filter doesnt work, I don't know why. 
I solved my problem for now: when checkbox is checked => I turn display:none with css. And that works combined with the number filter. But It's not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I have combined multiple Isotope filters before. You can see an example here: http://ashk3l.github.io/task-dashboard/tasks.html

The combined filter functions were created based on the [example in the Isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) that you can find under the subheading "Combination Filters".

Here is the code that combines the filters in the example above:

```
    //define parent container and empty array object
    var $container = $('.task-container');
    filters = {};

    // store filter for each group
    var filters = {};

    $('ul.dropdown-menu li').on('click', 'a', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // get group key
        var $dropdownGroup = $this.parents('.dropdown');
        var filterGroup = $dropdownGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
        // set filter for group
        filters[filterGroup] = $this.attr('data-filter');
        // combine filters
        var filterValue = concatValues(filters);
        $container.isotope({
            filter: filterValue
        });
    });

    // flatten object by concatting values
    function concatValues(obj) {
        var value = '';
        for (var prop in obj) {
            value += obj[prop];
        }
        return value;
    }
```